# Reference to a derived template class object incorrectly passed to overloaded operator<< body

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

I use Visual Studio 2019 compiler. For educational purposes I have decided to implement/create a template based FIFO queue. To achieve that I decided to inherit earlier implemented and well functioning doubly linked list (template based as well).
Here is the code which I purposefully simplified for presentation clarity purposes (I removed all the insignificant member functions declarations and definitions):

**Doubly_linked_list.h :**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class list;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list<T>& arg);

template <class T>
class list
{
protected:
    struct node
    {
        T* obj_ptr;
        node* next_node_ptr;
        node* previous_node_ptr;
        node()
            : next_node_ptr(NULL), previous_node_ptr(NULL), obj_ptr(NULL) {}
    };

    node* first_node_ptr;
    node* last_node_ptr;
    node* chosen_node_ptr;

    int element_counter;

public:
    list()
    {
        first_node_ptr = last_node_ptr = chosen_node_ptr = NULL;
        element_counter = 0;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& out, const list<T>& arg);

    void set_chosen_after_last()
    {
        chosen_node_ptr = NULL;
    }

    void add_element(T& obj);

    ~list();

private:
    void add_element_as_first(node* newly_added_node_ptr);
    void add_element_as_last(node* newly_added_node_ptr);
    void add_element_in_middle(node* newly_added_node_ptr);
};
//##################################################################################
//##################################################################################


template <class T>
list<T>::~list()
{
    if (!first_node_ptr) 
        return;

    node* bishop;
    int i;
    cout << "\n\n";

    for (chosen_node_ptr = first_node_ptr, i = 0; chosen_node_ptr; i++)
    {
        bishop = chosen_node_ptr->next_node_ptr;
        delete chosen_node_ptr;
        chosen_node_ptr = bishop;
    }
}


template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list<T>& arg)
{
    if (!(arg.first_node_ptr))
        return out;

    typename list<T>::node* chaser = arg.first_node_ptr;

    for (; chaser; chaser = chaser->next_node_ptr)
    {
        out << *(chaser->obj_ptr) << "\t";
    }

    return out;
}


template <class T>
void list<T>::add_element_in_middle(node* newly_added_node_ptr)
{
    node* previous_node = chosen_node_ptr->previous_node_ptr;
    previous_node->next_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
    newly_added_node_ptr->previous_node_ptr = previous_node;
    newly_added_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = chosen_node_ptr;
    chosen_node_ptr->previous_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
    chosen_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
}


template <class T>
void list<T>::add_element_as_last(node* newly_added_node_ptr)
{
    last_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
    newly_added_node_ptr->previous_node_ptr = last_node_ptr;
    last_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
}



template <class T>
void list<T>::add_element_as_first(node* newly_added_node_ptr)
{
    if (!first_node_ptr)   
    {
        first_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
        last_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        newly_added_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = first_node_ptr;
        first_node_ptr->previous_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
        first_node_ptr = newly_added_node_ptr;
        chosen_node_ptr = first_node_ptr;
    }
}

template <class T>
void list<T>::add_element(T& obj)
{
    node* new_node_ptr = new node;
    new_node_ptr->obj_ptr = &obj;

    if (!first_node_ptr || chosen_node_ptr == first_node_ptr)
        add_element_as_first(new_node_ptr);
    else
    {
        if (!chosen_node_ptr)
        {
            add_element_as_last(new_node_ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            add_element_in_middle(new_node_ptr);
        }
    }

    element_counter++;
}
```

**Queue.h :**

```
#pragma once
#include "Doubly_linked_list.h"

template <class t>
class queue;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, typename const queue<T>& arg);

template <class T>
class queue : private list<T>
{
public:
    void push(T arg)
    {
        list<T>::set_chosen_after_last();
        list<T>::add_element(arg);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& out, typename const queue<T>& arg);
};


template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, typename const queue<T>& arg)
{
    if (!(arg.list<T>::first_node_ptr))
        return out;

    typename list<T>::node* chaser = arg.first_node_ptr;

    for (; chaser; chaser = chaser->next_node_ptr)
    {
        out << *(chaser->obj_ptr) << "\t";
    }

    return out;
}
```

**Main.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"


int main()
{
    queue<int> ex1;
    ex1.push(5);

    cout << ex1;
}
```

As a result of testing the above code I was expecting the number 5 to be printed on the console, the result is however some random integer number (different each time I run this code) like this one:

> 7599868

I started debugging my code and noticed that arg, being rhs argument for overloaded operator<< and also being the reference to ex1 object, somehow has its obj_ptr pointing at integer object of value different than 5 inside the overloaded operator body. Instead the value is the random one eventually printed on the console as you can see on below screen shot from the debugger mode:

[Debugger_mode_screen_shot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKYq.png)

I am now running out of ideas on the possible root cause of such a behavior. To my knowledge arg should refer to the exact same object in memory as ex1, hence their obj_ptr pointers should point at the exact same object of type T (integer in this case) and of the exact same value (5 in this case). Although this is not what actually happens. I have read through numerous topics here on SO and could not find any of them that would address this particular situation/issue.

What is even more interesting and leading me to a greater confusion is the fact that I have tried to recreate this issue by writing a separate simple code imitating the inheritance mechanisms used in the original code. Here however the results are totally as expected - reference to an inherited template class object is being passed to the overloaded operator correctly (with the correct value of integer object pointed at by ptr_a pointer) and hence the console eventually prints out the correct value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Base;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Base<T>& arg);


template <class T>
class Base
{
protected:
    struct node
    {
        T* ptr_a;
        node* next_node_ptr;

        node()
        {
            ptr_a = new T;
            next_node_ptr = NULL;
        }
    };

    node* first_node_ptr;

public:
    Base()
    {
        first_node_ptr = new node;
        *(first_node_ptr->ptr_a) = 5;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& out, Base<T>& arg);
};


template <class t>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Base<t>& arg)
{
    cout << "this is " << *arg.first_node_ptr->ptr_a << endl;
    return out;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <class T>
class Deriv;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Deriv<T>& arg);

template <class T>
class Deriv : private Base<T>
{
public:
    void new_function() {}

    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& out, const Deriv& arg);
};


template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Deriv<T>& arg)
{
    cout << "This is " << *arg.first_node_ptr->ptr_a << endl;
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    Base<int> ex1;
    cout << ex1;

    Deriv<int> ex2;
    cout << ex2;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> this is 5
> This is 5
> ```

It is worth mentioning that the overloading operator<< worked perfectly fine for list < T > when I originally implemented it. Also I tried to use Code::Blocks to test this code but the issue persisted there as well. As you can also see I befriended operator<< by first forward declaring it before implementing the actual template class definition (to let the friendship always be constituted for a given type parameter particularly and not for all possible types at once). This method has worked perfectly fine for me in list < T > and in all the previous similar codes.

Can any of you guys point out a possible root cause of this situation and what exactly I should do now to make it work as expected (in this case to print 5 instead of some random number)? Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Your code stores a pointer to an object which is afterwards destroyed. When you dereference this pointer this is undefined behaviour and explains the garbage value you see.

Answer (score 0):

This code stores a pointer to the object referred to by `obj`.

```
template <class T>
void list<T>::add_element(T& obj)
{
    node* new_node_ptr = new node;
    new_node_ptr->obj_ptr = &obj;
    ...
```

This code calls `list<T>::add_element` with a reference to a local object, namely `arg`.

```
void push(T arg)
{
    list<T>::set_chosen_after_last();
    list<T>::add_element(arg);
}
```

Once `push` has exited the pointer stored by `add_element` is invalid. This explains the garbage value you see when you later use the pointer.

The solution is not to store pointers in your nodes but to copy or move the objects passed to your list and queue functions to your nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much @john ! I had a feeling that I had still been missing some easy yet "invisible" detail in my code... And here it is, a mistake that I usually do not make... :) I was still looking at the wrong part of my code looking for a bug... Shame on me :) But still lesson learnt.

Comment: I have now changed push function prototype from **void push(T arg)** to **void push(T& arg)** and in the main function, as the **push** function argument, I use actual integer object/variable instead of rvalue reference which I used originally:

` int a = 5; 
ex1.push(a); `

It is now all working perfectly fine. Thank you one more time!

Comment: Also I am now too "young" for this forum to give you proper credit in the form of additional point (I created an account here just yesterday) and SO would not allow me to give points at the moment.